# Node js Graph Search

Tags: node.js, database, search, graph

I am creating a social application using Nodejs and MySql.
I have a table named **Followers**. The fields are: **Follower** and **Following**.

For explain my problem, i create some fake data in **Followers** table: (**Follower**, **Following**)

1. Amir, Reza
2. Amir, Meghdad
3. Amir, Batman
4. Amir, David
5. Reza, Mohammad
6. Meghdad, Mohammad
7. Batman, Bastani
8. Mohammad, David
9. Bastani, Joseph

This is a network of '*Amir*' for explain what i want:
[image: Graph:]

Result what i want: (**User**, **Level**, **Connections**):

1. Reza, 0, 1
2. Meghdad, 0, 1
3. Batman, 0, 1
4. David, 0, 2
5. Mohammad, 1, 2
6. Bastani, 1, 1
7. Joseph, 2, 1

I could not do this with MySql, so i try the [levelgraph](https://www.npmjs.com/package/levelgraph) Database and it is confused me in **Level**s after 3. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Finally my own search get works:

```
let getNetwork = ( user, maxLevel = 5 )=>{
    let getLevel = ( user, level )=>{
        return new Promise( ( resolve, reject )=>{
            let search = [];
            for( let i = 0; i < level; i++ ){
                search.push(
                    {
                        subject: db.v( i ),
                        object: db.v( (i+1) )
                    }
                );
            }
            search[0].filter = obj => obj.subject == user && !( level > 1 && obj.trust < 1 );
            db.search(search, (error, results)=>{
                resolve( Object.keys( results ).map( i=>
                    Object.keys(results[i]).map( j=>
                        results[i][j]
                    )
                ) );
            });
        });
    }
    return new Promise( ( resolve, reject )=>{
        let ret = [];
        let getLevels = function (i=1){
            if( i > maxLevel ){
                resolve( ret );
            }
            else{
                getLevel( user, i ).then( (lvlX)=>{
                    ret = ret.concat( lvlX );
                    getLevels( i+1 );
                });
            }
        }
        getLevels();

    });
}
getNetwork('Amir').then( console.log );
```